# Flutter: detect onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward from different widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

This is my ads state provider:

```
getRewardedAd() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      _rewardedAd ??= RewardedAd(
        adUnitId: RewardedAd.testAdUnitId,
        request: request,
        listener: AdListener(
            onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
              print('${ad.runtimeType} loaded.');
              _rewardedReady = true;
            },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
              print('${ad.runtimeType} failed to load: $error');
              ad.dispose();
              _rewardedAd = null;
              getRewardedAd();
            },
            onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('${ad.runtimeType} onAdOpened.'),
            onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {
              print('${ad.runtimeType} closed.');
              ad.dispose();
              getRewardedAd();
            },
            onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) =>
                print('${ad.runtimeType} onApplicationExit.'),
            onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward:
                (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem reward) {
               // REWARDED
            }),
      )..load();
    }

    return _rewardedAd;
  }

  showRewardedAd() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) return;
    _rewardedAd!.show();
    _rewardedReady = false;
    _rewardedAd = null;
  }
```

And this is my other widget/page/class from where I'm calling the video from:

```
PlatformButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await loading.load(
                  context,
                  translate('loads.loading_video'),
                );
                Provider.of<AdState>(context, listen: false).showRewardedAd();
                loading.cancel();
              },
              child: PlatformText(translate('reward_video.watch')),
              material: (_, __) => MaterialRaisedButtonData(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                textColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              cupertino: (_, __) => CupertinoButtonData(),
            ),
```

When using firebase_admob I detected the rewarded video like this directly from the widget I was testing it:

```
// OLD firebase_admob IMPLEMENTATION
@override
  void initState() {
    ads.myVideo.listener =
            (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
          if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.loaded) {
            loading.cancel();
            ads.showVideo();
          }
          if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
            // rewarded!
          }
        };
       super.initState();
  }
```

Now with this new library I'm not sure how to listen to this changes from here, the docs don't give too much info about this.
When I try to do something similar to the code above it says that `'onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward' can't be used as a setter because it's final.` or that `'listener' can't be used as a setter because it's final.`

Answer (score 0):

Here i have an example of new google mobile ads implementation

```
RewardedAd _rewardedAd;

void loadVideoAd() async {
    _rewardedAd = RewardedAd(
      adUnitId: AdManager.rewardedAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          _rewardedAd.show();
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          ad.dispose();
          _rewardedAd = null;
        },
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {
          ad.dispose();
        },
        onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) =>
            print('${ad.runtimeType} onApplicationExit.'),
        onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem reward) {
          HomeScreen(rewardAmount: reward.amount);
        },
      ),
    );

    _rewardedAd.load();
  }

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int rewardAmount;

  HomeScreen({Key key, this.rewardAmount}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}
```

To pass it to other class just pass the "reward.amount" to another class.
Maybe if you give more details on your code, i can help you.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I have but how do you pass that reward to the other class?

Comment: The old way I shared was a listener that could add anywhere. Cannot do something like that now?

Comment: @Dani use constructor, the one that used to pass variables.

Comment: Could you update your answer with that listener pls?

Comment: Please give me more details about the class you want to pass the reward amount into

Comment: Ok, I added everything now. Hope it sounds more clear

Comment: basically what I'd need it to listen for that onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward outside of my provider. That provider should be transparent and return/load the ads, but not do any logic inside